# index bundle chunk is too big

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm new to code splitting with React and Webpack so I'm not sure if this is an OK size for a bundle chunk.

I tried to split my React app based on the routes ([basically done the same thing as in the example in the React doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting)).

This works fine, but the main bundle which contains the index of my app (i.e. rendering my app to the DOM) seems quite big (~400Ko), and I don't really know what could be removed, everything included seems essential (My app uses apollo, react, redux, styled-components).

Here's the index.js so you can have a look at the dependencies:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider as StoreProvider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { store, persistor } from 'STORE/index';
import App from './App';

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql'
});

const render = (App) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
      <StoreProvider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </PersistGate>
      </StoreProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};

render(App);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./App', () => {
    render(require('./App'));
    console.log('App updated successfully.');
  });
}
```

Again, I'm new to code splitting so maybe this is an OK size but webpack keeps telling me that the size of the bundle is too big.

Thanks again !

EDIT: Here's a look at a [webpack bundle analyzer of my app if that helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7i9S.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

This unfortunately a problem when using apollo-client together with react because both are required in the entry point of the app :/

Seems like apollo- client is working on it: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4324